# Lambda Return Payload botocore.response.StreamingBody object prints but then empty in variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-2.x

I'm invoking a lambda function from another function and want to take a different action depending on the response, pretty standard stuff. However I get some unexpected behavior, it's probably something obvious, but it is eluding me. I've recreated my example in the simplest possible example any help would be much appreciated.

The lambda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return 'Just a string'
```

The code to call the lambda function

```
    def invoke_lambda(payload):
        r = lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName='MyLambdaFunction',
            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
            Payload=bytes(payload)
        )

    p = r['Payload'].read()
    print p #Prints an empty string
    print(r['Payload'].read()) #Prints Just a string
    invoke_lambda(payload)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following code solves the problem. Apparently I need to set the streamingbody to a variable, then read it into another variable. I used this [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221549) for reference

```
def invoke_lambda(payload):
    r = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='MyLambdaFunction',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=bytes(payload)
    )
    t = r['Payload']
    j = t.read()
    print j
```

Comment: t.read() returnin binary string, so easily convert j.decode("utf-8") etc

Comment: Broken link in 2023

Comment: NOTE: you can only invoke `.read()` once! It's some sort of iterator. So if you're debugging the problem with a print statement you'll get a blank value when you call `.read()` again.

Answer (score 25):

If you expect JSON as response, you can do the following:

```
import json

def invoke_lambda(payload):
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='MyLambdaFunction',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=bytes(payload)
    )  

    response_payload = json.loads(invoke_response['Payload'].read().decode("utf-8"))

    print ("response_payload: {}".format(response_payload))
```

Comment: This should also work: ```response_payload = json.load(invoke_response['Payload'])```  Note json.load instead of json.loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    PayloadForInvoker = {'Param1': 'abcdj', 'Param2': 50 }

    response = client.invoke(
```

FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:Region:AccountId:function:FunctionToInvokeName',
InvocationType='RequestResponse', # If the invoke is synchornous otherwise use Event
Payload=json.dumps(PayloadForInvoker)
)

```
    response_payload = json.load(response['Payload'])


    print ("response_payload: {}".format(response_payload))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).