# Getting AWS Lambda response when using boto3 invoke()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Im currently writing a python script that interacts with some AWS lambda functions. In one of the functions, my response contains a list which I need in my script.

Problem is that when I use the `invoke()` function, the response is a json which contains request information.

```
response = aws_lambdaClient.invoke(FunctionName = 'functionName', Payload = payload)
```

The function that im using has this as a return

```
return {'names': aList, 'status': 'Success!'}
```

If I print out the response, I get this:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Thu, 07 Nov 2019 14:28:25 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '51', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'x-amzn-remapped-content-length': '0', 'x-amz-executed-version': '$LATEST', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'root=xxxxxxxxx;sampled=0'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'StatusCode': 200, 'ExecutedVersion': '$LATEST', 'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x0000023D15716048>}
```

And id like to get

```
{'names': aList, 'status': 'Success!'}
```

Any idea on how can I achieve this? Or should I find another way of getting the data (Maybe putting the list i need in an s3 bucket and then getting it from there).

Comment: `Payload` contains the Lambda's response.

Comment: What would be the way of accessing that payload? It seems that it indicates a memory position

Comment: I don't know python, but as per the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) it's a `StreamingBody`, which is defined [here](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody) - seems you just call `read()` on it to get the value. E.g. `response['Payload'].read()` or so. This link suggests it may need to be assigned to a variable first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294802

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Manuel,

as mentioned, the return info is inside the Payload element in the returned json.  Payload is a boto3 object type that you need to access it's contents through it's read() method.

The code I used to get the python dictionary that I return from my lambda functions is this:

```
payload = json.loads(response['Payload'].read())

statusCode = payload.get('statusCode')
message = payload.get('message')
results = payload.get('results')
```

Comment: hey @richard, response['Payload'].read() gives null but another lambda is returning correct response if checked separately

Comment: @PainPoints i have the same problem, response is `null` after .read() call. Any finding on this?

Comment: @NebiMAydin is your VPC attached to internet gateway ? The boto3 client doesn't work if your VPC does not have IG attached.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using InvocationType='Event', You must use InvocationType='RequestResponse',

As per the  [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)

RequestResponse (default) – Invoke the function synchronously. Keep the connection open until the function returns a response or times out. The API response includes the function response and additional data.

Event – Invoke the function asynchronously. Send events that fail multiple times to the function's dead-letter queue (if one is configured). The API response only includes a status code.

DryRun – Validate parameter values and verify that the user or role has permission to invoke the function.