# Lambda Function not able to invoke sagemaker endpoint

Tags: json, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

```
predict = [0.1,0.2]
payload = {
    "instances":    [
        {
            "features": predict
        }
    ]
}
response = linear_regressor.predict(json.dumps(payload))
predictions = json.loads(response)
print(json.dumps(predictions, indent=2))
```

The above code is able to invoke the endpoint which is the linear-learner endpoint and give the below result.

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "score": 0.13421717286109924
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to invoke the endpoint using below lambda function,

```
import json 
import io
import boto3 

client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    #data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    #payload = data['data']
    #print(payload)

    response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='linear-learner-2019-12-12-16-xx-xx-xxx',
                                  ContentType='application/json',
                                  Body=json.dumps(event))
    return response
```

I get the following error,

```
    An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: 
<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7fc941e7e828> is not JSON serializable
```

The input for the lambda function is the same,

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "features": [
        0.1,
        0.2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what is causing the issue here. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try using boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime') instead?

Comment: @velociraptor11, Yes I tried that, still same error. I believe the problem is in the JSON format that I am sending to the endpoint, not able to find any documentation/sample request format.

Comment: Reason I asked is because your code seems just about right. I am passing json.dumps() to the Body of invoke endpoint and it's no problem at all. Try removing "Content Type" from the function call. So only `client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='linear-learner-2019-12-12-16-xx-xx-xxx',
           
                                  Body=json.dumps(event))` I think it could be due to the fact that you are passing a string and the client call is expecting a json

Comment: No luck with removing the Content Type as well,still getting same error.Are you using linear-learner endpoint as well in your lambda.

Comment: I'm not. I am using the MxNet custom deploy container as well as a Tensorflow serving container. I think best way is to raise an issue in the Github page and maybe they can help you from there. They typically reply pretty fast

Comment: I was able to solve this based on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294802/lambda-return-payload-botocore-response-streamingbody-object-prints-but-then-emp", the error was in the response and not in the payload. I was was not paying close attention the error since it clearly says the error is in the response :(.