# boto3 lambda payload always returns NULL [python, sync invoked]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, github-actions, aws-step-functions

I am using Lambda to trigger a step function. It works fine in terms of triggering the step function, but I also need the lambda to return the state machine **execution arn** (NOT state machine arn). I need the execution arn because I am implementing the whole process as a github action workflow, so I need it to check the status (running/success/failed/aborted) of the state machine.

My code of getting the lambda return for github action, wrapped as docker-compose service:

```
client = boto3.client("lambda", region_name="us-west-1")
lambda_response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName="my-lambda",
    InvocationType="RequestResponse",
    Payload=json.dumps({"detail-type": "gh-action"}),
)
payload = json.loads(lambda_response["Payload"].read()) # tried .decode() too
print("payload:", payload) # payload prints None as a whole, not {"sfn_exe_arn": None}
```

The relevant part of my lambda function:

```py
    try:
        client = boto3.client("stepfunctions")
        response = client.start_execution(
            stateMachineArn=STATE_MACHINE_ARN,
            name=run_name,
            input=json.dumps(
                {"runName": run_name, "model_name": MODEL_NAME, "queries": QUERIES}
            ),
        )
        sfn_exe_arn = response["executionArn"]
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
  
    return {"sfn_exe_arn": sfn_exe_arn}
    # this `sfn_exe_arn` can print out with expected value in console
    # but it does not return when called in github action
```

When I invoke this lambda from the console, most of the time it returns as expected, which is `{"sfn_exe_arn": sfn_exe_arn}`, but sometime it also returns `null`.

When I invoke this lambda as part of github action workflow, the return is always `null` (the `lambda_response` is returned, just the `payload` part is always `null`)

Can anyone help me understand why there is this gap? apparently my lambda got the executionArn, but it just doesn't return to the `client.invoke()`

The entire `lambda_response` (it is named `response` in the screenshot):
[image]

Comment: Sometimes it returns null, or it returns `{"sfn_exe_arn": null}`?

Comment: it return `null` as a whole, even when I make lambda to return a constant string, it's still `null`. Thank you for the clarifying question~

Comment: I'm guessing that it failed, e.g. timed out. Print the entire `lambda_response` object.

Comment: Hi @jarmod, I just added the screenshot of the entire response at the bottom of the post, it has StatusCode: 200. I tried to fail it purposely before, it does throw error when I did so.

Comment: Could it be that the StreamingBody read is still not a deserialized format ? 
Could you try `lambda_response["Payload"].read().decode()`.
Guess that should be it, because `StreamingBody.read()` still return a `bytes`object.

Comment: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.read

Comment: I am wondering how to check if there is a racing condition, I am not familiar with the concept and can't think of any, but it's really weird that, even inside the console, the lambda returns null sometime as well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294802/lambda-return-payload-botocore-response-streamingbody-object-prints-but-then-emp

Comment: Hi @jarmod, that did fix this problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the bytestream that you get from StreamingBody.read()

add `.decode()` to the `bytes` object you get from reading the reponse payload.

```
payload = json.loads(lambda_response["Payload"].read().decode())
```

Comment: Hi @lwohlart, I really hope this is the answer. I tried adding decode() as the way you wrote, but the print is exact same, still None, but thank you for offering help!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I didn't try thoroughly other posts' answers. Thanks @jarmod pointed out the solution in the comments: you need to assign `StreamingBody` to a variable before read it. Link: [Lambda Return Payload botocore.response.StreamingBody object prints but then empty in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294802/lambda-return-payload-botocore-response-streamingbody-object-prints-but-then-emp)